# Create new customer not redirect to My account after Magento upgrade to 1.9.3.4

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, register

I have upgraded to Magento 1.9.3.4. Everything working fine only after create a new customer it's not redirecting to My account page. It is redirecting to Home page and showing notification that your account is created on Home page.

I want to redirect it to My account page of customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of struggle, I got answer of this.

I added below missing form key code in `app/design/frontend/[your_package]/[your_theme]/template/customer/form/register.phtml` file:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```